# Use of max command inside quicksum - gurobi with python

Tags: python, gurobi, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to include a python "max" command inside a quicksum command using gurobi with python. There is obviously an error with doing so, under LinExpr limitations as it is not accepted.

```
shutdowncost = quicksum(quicksum(shutdown_cost[i] * max((v[hour -1, i] - v[hour, i]),0) for i in num_gen) for hour in hour_range)
```

V is a binary variable in the model, while the remainder are fixed variables. The issue is around shutdowncost being negative in the scenario where v[hour - 1, i] is 0, and v[hour, i] is 1.

Is there another command that can be used to replace the max command inside the quicksum?

Comment: is this operation allowed : `list.sort(reverse=True)[0]` ?

Comment: Why do you use `gurobi`? What about solving in pure Python (with `numpy` for example)?

Comment: Using gurobi for the optimisation toolbox. Thanks for the comments - I was able to remedy the issue by introducing new variables for the shutdowncost and constrain it to be equal to this command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a paper that talks about startup and shutdown constraints: [MIPFormulation](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2014/07/4433.pdf).  They use the notation:

- u[t] 1 for online, 0 for offline, binary (state)
- v[t] 1 for turned on that time period, binary (turn_on)
- w[t] 1 for turned off that period, binary (turn_off)

These gurobi binary variables are defined with the constraints:

- u[t] - u[t-1] == v[t] - w[t]
- v[t] + w[t] <= 1

Then your shutdowncost can be defined:

- shutdowncost = quicksum([shutdown_cost[i] * w[hour, i] for i in num_gen for hour in hour_range])

(No need for 2 quicksums!)
This shutdowncost can then be used in your objective function or another constraint. And it is easier to see what is happening.